# What does ね mean in「ここなんだけどね」?

Tags: particle-ね

The character (かがみ) is asking her sister to explain something, so she points to the textbook and says:「ここなんだけど**ね**」. It's translated (presumably correctly?) as: "I'm talking about this". (The sister responds with 「かがみが　わからないところは 私に分かるわけないでしょう」.)

What is the role of the **ね** particle here? I thought **ね** would reflect some feelings or thoughts that are (expected to be) shared between the two people. But this meaning doesn't seem to fit here.